# Xcode 4.2 Lion not installing / running project on older devices. iPhone 3G 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

XCode 4.2 Build 4D199 on Lion with iPhone 3G IOS 4.2.1

Project with Base SDK 5.0 and Target 4.2.

On this phone and on older iTouch the debugger never seems to startup.  After pushing RUN the project compiles and then the Debug entry is in the Log Navigator with the Spinner Running. The spinner never stops and the app does not get loaded on the iPhone 3G.

Any clues on how to fix.  This was working fine before the Lion Upgrade.

Need to test the older devices.  Newer devices seem to work fine.

Device seems to be provisioned fine, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably because armv6 is missing from the architectures for the Target.

Click on your Project in Xcode, then click on the Target. Double-click on 'Architectures', and delete what's current there - probably something like $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) - using the '-' button. Next, click on the '+' button and add 'armv7', then add 'armv6'.

Hopefully, that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, with the current version, it won't let me choose an armv6, but it does have an entry lower saying "Valid Architectures" and it lists armv6, armv7.  Will get back, restoring the phone now to see if that helps.

Comment: Well, does not seem to work.  iTouch 2G will not work with the debugger for some reason.  Will neet to get this working soon....

Comment: @ort11 - I can verify that this does work.  I just did something similar (remove the existing architecture and manually add armv6 and armv7) to build and install an application on my iPhone 3G using the final stable version of Xcode 4.2.  See this Apple Developer Forum thread for more: https://devforums.apple.com/message/507419

Comment: @BradLarson you are running (Build 4D199)? I'm starting to think I'm the only one for whom this isn't working.

Comment: @NJones - Yes, that's the build I'm running.  Works fine here.  Make sure that you don't have a target architecture setting that's overriding your project ones.  If it helps, here is the project I tested this on, which should build and deploy to older devices as well as new ones: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Molecules-10182011.zip

Comment: @BradLarson your referenced project ran on my iPod touch 2nd Gen. I haven't had a chance to check for the differences yet, but at least now I have something to compare. THANK YOU!

Comment: Ok, I got it to go.  The one thing that I was missing is that you may have to ADD the armv6 to be able to add to the list.  I missed that from the first reply.  So, if only armv7 is listed, add in armv6 and then both armv6 and armv7 will be on the line.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I found when I would start a new project in xCode 4.2 (Build 4D199) it would not build to my iPod touch running 4.2.1. While I did have to set my architectures to include armv6, that alone did not do it.

In my project's Info.plist file xCode had set "Required device capabilities" to include 'armv7'. I removed that now everything is working fine.

I hope this helps someone else.