# Building for prior iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.2 Lion not installing / running project on older devices. iPhone 3G 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770221/xcode-4-2-lion-not-installing-running-project-on-older-devices-iphone-3g-4-2)

I surrender.  After removing xCode 4.1 and installing 4.2 I cannot build and run on development devices running iOS 4.2.1. (iPad/iPhone simulator only shows 4.3 and 5.0)  I did not have the problem when we moved to iOS 4.0 from 3.2.1.

I have the deployment target set to 3.0 and the base sdk set to latest iOS (iOS 5.0)  Under build options I have tried setting LLVM 3.0 and GCC 4.2 without any difference.  It compiles and says it has finished running on device - although it has not.

Did I miss something?

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770221/xcode-4-2-lion-not-installing-running-project-on-older-devices-iphone-3g-4-2/7797318#comment9519224_7797318

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!  Sorry I couldn't find that on my own.

Comment: I submitted that comment as an answer. If it helped please accept it.

Comment: @ScottCorscadden i think yes ;) Can you close it?